# Setting custom MariaDB max_allowed_packet value in Debian 11?

Tags: debian, mariadb

Our Moodle server, running Debian 11 (bullseye), now seems to produce an "Error writing to database" message in the web browser when course admins try to manually backup some (larger) courses.

The error message links to [error/moodle/dmlwriteexception](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/error/moodle/dmlwriteexception), which says that we may need to increase the DB server's `max_allowed_packet` setting.

The page refers to MySQL, but we are running MariaDB (v10.5.15), although I expect the issue will be similar(?).

Indeed, the MariaDB config still seems to be inside `/etc/mysql/`, but I am not sure which config file I may need to change (or whether I can add an additional "local" 'override' file in one of the `*conf.d` folders) with the amended setting.

None of

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1126 Feb 18  2022 mariadb.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Jun 22  2020 my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  839 Aug  3  2016 my.cnf.fallback
```

contain a default `max_allowed_packet` value.

All of these files 'include' `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/`, and `my.cnf` and `mariadb.conf` both also 'include' `!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/` as well.

In the `*conf.d` folders, `max_allowed_packet` is referred to in the following:

```
conf.d/mysqldump.cnf:max_allowed_packet = 16M
mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:#max_allowed_packet     = 1G
```

In MariaDB itself, when we query `show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';`, it returns `16777216` (= 16M), which seems to correspond to the issue we seem to be having with larger files (100 MB+).

I note that the value in `mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` is commented out. If we were to add an additional conf file in that folder (I prefer not to directly edit the OS-installed config files, if possible) with a larger value, uncommented/enabled, would that be the right place/way for us to increase this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new config file like this:

```
cat > /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-custom_config.cnf <<EOF
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=256M
EOF
```

Don't forget to restart MariaDB to apply the updated config:

```
systemctl restart mariadb
```

Then double check that it worked:

```
mysql -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';"
```

You should see this:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name      | Value     |
+--------------------+-----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 268435456 |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

:)

Comment: Not worked for me. | max_allowed_packet | 4194304 |